# Mongodb Java query never returns a value

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying to build a simple lookup of a mongodb database using the below code. On runtime, the code runs but never returns a value.

The generated query works in the command line no problem. The database is quite large, around 2.8gb.

```
public static void main(String[]args){

        String customer="peter";
        String job="builder";


        // To connect to mongodb server
        MongoClient mongoClient=new MongoClient("localhost",27017);

        // Now connect to your databases
        MongoDatabase db=mongoClient.getDatabase("customers");
        System.out.println("Connect to database successfully");

        // Now connect to your collection
        MongoCollection<Document> collection=db.getCollection("customerData");
        System.out.println("Connect to collection");

        BasicDBObject andQuery=new BasicDBObject();
        List<BasicDBObject> obj=new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>();

        obj.add(new BasicDBObject("job",job));
        obj.add(new BasicDBObject("customer",customer));
        andQuery.put("$and",obj);

        System.out.println(andQuery.toString());

        FindIterable<Document> iterable=collection.find(new Document(andQuery));
        MongoCursor<Document> iterableDocument=iterable.iterator();

        while(iterableDocument.hasNext()){
          Document wholeDocument=(Document)iterableDocument.next();
          System.out.println("1: "+wholeDocument.get("age"));
          System.out.println("2: "+wholeDocument.get("dob"));
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try simplifying your query as

```
DBObject obj = new BasicDBObject();
 obj.put( "job", job );
 obj.put( "customer", customer );
collection.find(new Document(obj))
```

Also, getDatabase and getCollection don't do a connect. If you misspelled those parts, the query will return nothing because you are hitting an empty database. (the first connect attempt is when you call 'find'. If the database or collection don't exist, Mongo will create it if you write to it)